# What is a strategy for the never-ending feed?

Tags: javascript

that you see on sites like pinterest.com, twitter.com, etc.  It appears that as you scroll down the feed keeps getting populated.

How does the browser know when to add items to the feed.

Is it a scroll event of sort.  I have all the server code I need, I know how to deliver the JSON and render it.  I just need to understand the glue code for when to send the data.

I would imagine it is an event of sorts.

```
window.addEventListener ...
```

Comment: The popular term for the effect you're looking for is [the infinite scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infinite+scroll). Searching for questions about the same will help answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

There is indeed an event that fires on scroll. It's called `scroll`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll

Listening to that event you can then then query [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) and do some calculations to detect if you've reached the bottom.

Comment: and if you have reached the bottom, you load the next set of posts.